# saving formatted data in database php and showing in ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

`&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt neque augue, ut facilisis enim ullamcorper finibus. Nullam quis scelerisque ligula, ut blandit neque. Sed est erat, finibus ac erat et, convallis egestas tortor. Aenean dignissim mollis tellus ac scelerisque. Cras non purus ligula. Nullam malesuada maximus odio, ac bibendum arcu. Nulla in est at metus facilisis vehicula a sit amet tortor. Praesent vel viverra tellus. Maecenas quam mauris, pretium eget consectetur non, convallis ut massa. Donec pharetra quam porttitor molestie ultrices. Sed vestibulum ipsum at odio elementum faucibus.&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;Mauris ac tellus ac purus tristique auctor. Duis a turpis turpis. Integer accumsan sapien venenatis, consequat quam et, ullamcorper dolor. Nunc non felis a quam lobortis faucibus at sit amet elit. Cras aliquam tristique egestas. Vivamus quis lacinia neque. Integer consequat nisi nec efficitur euismod.&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;Duis malesuada lacus id turpis lacinia pharetra. Cras euismod, metus vitae molestie luctus, est erat faucibus sem, nec dignissim lorem nibh faucibus libero. Sed feugiat velit non hendrerit fermentum. Nunc eros arcu, bibendum vitae semper id, pellentesque eget erat. Suspendisse rhoncus laoreet dolor, aliquam posuere odio. Nam sodales magna nec justo lacinia, feugiat interdum orci convallis. Phasellus porttitor diam et vulputate malesuada. Phasellus dignissim justo nec nunc laoreet, vel bibendum ipsum ultrices. Pellentesque condimentum nisl eros, nec semper erat faucibus quis. Duis vehicula dignissim malesuada. Donec cursus turpis vitae vulputate tempor. In quis magna urna.&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;n&lt;/p&gt;n`

This is my sample data that i stored in database. When i saved it i save everything. My problem is when i try to retrieve the data i get extra `n` for every `whitespace`

The output i get from the above data is like this

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt neque augue, ut facilisis enim ullamcorper finibus. Nullam quis scelerisque ligula, ut blandit neque. Sed est erat, finibus ac erat et, convallis egestas tortor. Aenean dignissim mollis tellus ac scelerisque. Cras non purus ligula. Nullam malesuada maximus odio, ac bibendum arcu. Nulla in est at metus facilisis vehicula a sit amet tortor. Praesent vel viverra tellus. Maecenas quam mauris, pretium eget consectetur non, convallis ut massa. Donec pharetra quam porttitor molestie ultrices. Sed vestibulum ipsum at odio elementum faucibus.

nn

nn

nn

nn

nn

nn

Mauris ac tellus ac purus tristique auctor. Duis a turpis turpis. Integer accumsan sapien venenatis, consequat quam et, ullamcorper dolor. Nunc non felis a quam lobortis faucibus at sit amet elit. Cras aliquam tristique egestas. Vivamus quis lacinia neque. Integer consequat nisi nec efficitur euismod.

nn

nn

nn

nn

nn

nn

Duis malesuada lacus id turpis lacinia pharetra. Cras euismod, metus vitae molestie luctus, est erat faucibus sem, nec dignissim lorem nibh faucibus libero. Sed feugiat velit non hendrerit fermentum. Nunc eros arcu, bibendum vitae semper id, pellentesque eget erat. Suspendisse rhoncus laoreet dolor, aliquam posuere odio. Nam sodales magna nec justo lacinia, feugiat interdum orci convallis. Phasellus porttitor diam et vulputate malesuada. Phasellus dignissim justo nec nunc laoreet, vel bibendum ipsum ultrices. Pellentesque condimentum nisl eros, nec semper erat faucibus quis. Duis vehicula dignissim malesuada. Donec cursus turpis vitae vulputate tempor. In quis magna urna.

nn

n

n`

How to avoid showing the `n` i am showing the data in a `ckeditor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `n` are really `\n`, that means that in some part of your code you're removing the `\` and you end up with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;nn&lt;/p&gt;nn&lt;p&gt;
```

These are HTML entities that decode to the following.

```
</p>nn<p>nn</p>nn<p>&nbsp;</p>nn<p>nn</p>nn<p>
```

So they aren't only whitespaces.
The whitespace is `&nbsp;`.

If the data is actually correct but you just don't want the `nn` parts to show you can replace them after fetching your data from the database using `str_replace`

Something like this:

```
$nn = "&gt;nn&lt;"
$filtered_data = str_replace($nn, "&gt;&lt;", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use "htmlspecialchars_decode" php function.

```
<?php
```

echo htmlspecialchars_decode("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tincidunt neque augue, ut facilisis enim ullamcorper finibus. Nullam quis scelerisque ligula, ut blandit neque. Sed est erat, finibus ac erat et, convallis egestas tortor. Aenean dignissim mollis tellus ac scelerisque. Cras non purus ligula. Nullam malesuada maximus odio, ac bibendum arcu. Nulla in est at metus facilisis vehicula a sit amet tortor. Praesent vel viverra tellus. Maecenas quam mauris, pretium eget consectetur non, convallis ut massa. Donec pharetra quam porttitor molestie ultrices. Sed vestibulum ipsum at odio elementum faucibus.</p>nn<p>nn</p>nn<p>&nbsp;</p>nn<p>nn</p>nn<p>Mauris ac tellus ac purus tristique auctor. Duis a turpis turpis. Integer accumsan sapien venenatis,");